Is there a legitimate reference to the physical entrance that connects from Diagon Alley to Knockturn Alley?
According to the book "Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets," and tracing back Hagrid and Harry's steps, the entrance should be beside an apothecary, some distance from the Gringotts Bank building, along a twisting alleyway.
In contrast, the movie Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets (2002) depicts the entrance to Knockturn Alley with a pointing sign next to a shop named Tricks & Jokes and a library (which sells a series of books called Witch & Wizard, or so).
Is there a legitimate reference to the physical entrance that connects from Diagon Alley to Knockturn Alley?


No official map of the street exists and the locations of things is actually pretty vague.

The movies take some liberties with the books, and things don't necessarily match up...
